# Truffle test in solidity with sending value

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

I have a simple contract with public function, that can receive value and do something based on that value:

```
pragma solidity >= 0.8.0 < 0.9.0;

contract ContractA {


    uint public boughtItems = 0;
    uint price = 10;
    address []  buyers; 

    function buySomething() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= price, "Sent value is lower"); 
        boughtItems++;
        buyers.push(msg.sender);
    }
}
```

and in test folder of my Truffle project I have test contract:

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";
import "../contracts/TicketsRoutes.sol";

contract TestTicketsRoutes {

    ContractA instance;
    

    address account1 = 0xD8Ce37FA3A1A61623705dac5dCb708Bb5eb9a125;

    function beforeAll() public {
        instance = new ContractA();
    }

    function testBuying() public {
        //Here I need to invoke buySomething with specific value from specific address
        instance.buySomething();

        Assert.equal(instance.boughtItems, 1, "Routes amount is not equal");
    }
}
```

How do I invoke function of ContractA in my TestContractA with passing value and sender?

Answer (score 0):

First the test contract will need to have some initial balance balance. To achieve that define a public uint named `initialBalance` with the required amount. For other details read the section [Testing ether transactions](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-solidity).

```
contract TestTicketsRoutes {
    // Truffle will send the TestContract one Ether after deploying the contract.
    uint public initialBalance = 1 ether;
```

Solidity has a syntax that allows sending ether when invoking a function: `foo{value: amount}(param1, param2)`. Check the [solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/security-considerations.html#sending-and-receiving-ether).

```
function testBuying() public {
    // Here I need to invoke buySomething with specific value from specific address
    uint amount = 110;
    instance.buySomething{value: amount}();

    Assert.equal(instance.boughtItems, 1, "Routes amount is not equal");
}
```